# ASPX Select dropdown with Button Linking to another page

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I am unfamiliar with select dropdowns and links. If I have:

```
<select>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="/Applications.aspx">Applications</option>
    <option value="/EditApplications.aspx">Edit Application</option>
    <option value="/AddApplications.aspx">Add Applications</option>
</select>
<button>Go</button>
```

When the user selects their option, how do I link the button to when the user clicks the button, it goes to the selected page within the dropdown in ASPX? I am sure I need to bind it somehow to the codebehind but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic solution would be something like the snippet below. On the button click read the value of the select and redirect to that url. Don't forget to add an `id` to the `select`. And you need to add `type="button"` to the button, otherwise it will trigger a form post.

```
<select id="MySelect">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="/Applications.aspx">Applications</option>
    <option value="/EditApplications.aspx">Edit Application</option>
    <option value="/AddApplications.aspx">Add Applications</option>
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="GoTOUrl()">Go</button>

<script>
    function GoTOUrl() {
        var url = $('#MySelect').val();
        if (url === '')
            return;

        location.href = url;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Just a quick note for the OP that this requires the jQuery library.

Answer (score 1):

No need to wire it up to the code behind. This can all be handled client side with some javascript.

Make the button an actual link. Then update the `href` attribute and optionally the text.

```js
//Get relevent elements
var linkDropDown = document.getElementById("MySelect");
var link = document.getElementById("Link");

//Wire up event listener to the dropdown
linkDropDown.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var defaultVal = this.options[0].value;
  //Toggle the inactive class based on selected value
  link.classList.toggle("inactive", this.value === defaultVal);
  //Set Href
  link.href = this.value;
  //Set Text using ternary operation
  link.text = this.value === defaultVal ? "Go.." : "Go to " + this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;  
});
```

```css
.inactive {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<select id="MySelect">
  <option value="/">Select</option>
  <option value="/Applications.aspx">Applications</option>
  <option value="/EditApplications.aspx">Edit Application</option>
  <option value="/AddApplications.aspx">Add Applications</option>
</select>

<a href="/" id="Link" class="inactive">Go..</a>
```

It is also possible to encapsulate this to automagically work if you have more than set of this on the page.

```js
//Get relevent elements
var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdownSelect");

//Wire up event listeners
for(var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++){
  dropdowns[i].addEventListener("change", function(event){
    if(event.target.nodeName === "SELECT") {
      let sel = event.target;
      let link = this.querySelector(".dropdownLink");
      let defaultVal = sel.options[0].value;
      //Toggle the inactive class based on selected value
      link.classList.toggle("inactive", sel.value === defaultVal);
      //Set HREF
      link.href = sel.value;
      //Set Text using ternary operation
      link.text = sel.value === defaultVal ? "Go.." : "Go to " + sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.inactive {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdownSelect">
  <select>
    <option value="/">Select</option>
    <option value="/Applications.aspx">Applications</option>
    <option value="/EditApplications.aspx">Edit Application</option>
    <option value="/AddApplications.aspx">Add Applications</option>
  </select>

  <a href="/" class="dropdownLink inactive">Go..</a>
</div>
<div class="dropdownSelect">
  <select>
    <option value="/">Select</option>
    <option value="/WebSites.aspx">Web Sites</option>
    <option value="/EditWebSites.aspx">Edit Web Sites</option>
    <option value="/AddWebSites.aspx">Add Websites</option>
  </select>

  <a href="/" class="dropdownLink inactive">Go..</a>
</div>
```